# How can I create a circular progress indicator takes both positive and negative values and can go ant-clockwise as well?

Tags: flutter, progress-bar, direction, negative-number, flutter-circularprogressindicator

Is it possible to create a circular progress indicator that can do all the things in reverse direction as well?

For example if it takes positive values it goes clockwise and turns green for values above 0, if it gets negative values it goes anti-clockwise and turns to red for values under 0.